dragAndDropTarget not trigger in the dragAndDropTraget syntax
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ZoomableRotatableImage(urisList: SnapshotStateList<Uri>?, currentIndex: Int) {
    var zoom by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var rotation by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val minScale = 0.5f
    val maxScale = 2f
    val context = LocalContext.current

    // Remember dragged image index
    var draggedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(-1) } // Initialize to an invalid index

    val imagePainter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(urisList?.get(currentIndex))

    Image(
        painter = imagePainter,
        contentDescription = "Image $currentIndex",
        contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .graphicsLayer(
                scaleX = zoom,
                scaleY = zoom,
                translationX = offsetX,
                translationY = offsetY,
                rotationZ = rotation
            )
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTransformGestures { _, pan, gestureZoom, gestureRotate ->
                    zoom = (zoom * gestureZoom).coerceIn(minScale, maxScale)
                    rotation += gestureRotate
                    offsetX += pan.x * zoom
                    offsetY += pan.y * zoom
                }
            }
            .dragAndDropSource {
                detectTapGestures(
                    onLongPress = {
                        draggedIndex = currentIndex // Store the index of the dragged image
                        Log.d("DRAG_EVENT", "Dragging image at index $draggedIndex")
                        startTransfer(
                            DragAndDropTransferData(
                                clipData = ClipData.newIntent(
                                    "imageTransfer",
                                    Intent().apply {
                                        putExtra("imageResId", urisList?.get(currentIndex)) // Pass the image URI
                                    }
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
            .dragAndDropTarget(
                shouldStartDragAndDrop = { true },
                target = object : DragAndDropTarget {
                    override fun onDrop(event: DragAndDropEvent): Boolean {
                        Log.d("DRAG_EVENT", "Dropped on index $currentIndex")

                        // Only swap if dragging from a different index
                        if (draggedIndex != -1 && draggedIndex != currentIndex) {
                            urisList?.let {
                                // Swap images in the urisList
                                val temp = it[draggedIndex]
                                it[draggedIndex] = it[currentIndex]
                                it[currentIndex] = temp
                                Log.d("DRAG_EVENT", "Swapped images: $draggedIndex <-> $currentIndex")
                            }
                        }
                        // Reset dragged index
                        draggedIndex = -1
                        return true
                    }
                }
            )
    )
}


I implemented drag-and-drop using Jetpack Compose’s dragAndDropSource and dragAndDropTarget. I added logging to the drag start (onLongPress) and drop event (onDrop) to check when an image is dragged and dropped.

The drag initiation works fine, and I can see the logs from the onLongPress event in the dragAndDropSource, but the logs inside the onDrop method within dragAndDropTarget are not printing when I try to drop an image on another target.


